# What if an electron is sent through a double slit which has slits with spin based?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electrons, interference, double-slit-experiment

Imagine there is a double slit set up like one of it slits let only spin up electrons to go through and the another one let only spin down electron to go through it, so if we go on shooting electrons for which we do not know what spin it has on any axis, what pattern would form on the detector? Is it an interference or a random spread pattern?

Comment: Related questions with light:  [Double slit with opposite circular polarizers](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/247005/double-slit-with-opposite-circular-polarizers), [Double-slit with polarizing filter](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/616850/double-slit-with-polarizing-filter).  The answer to this question is pretty much the same.

Comment: The EM field is responsible for interference ... even before the electron has left the electrode it is excited and strongly interacting with the EM field.  If the electron's EM field interaction can see thru both slits then this field will give an interference pattern.  The fact that you have gates on the slits is going to limit the particles EM field interaction to one slit or the other.

Answer (score 2):

The pattern would be that of diffraction by a single slit. The parts of the wave function coming from each slit are mutually orthogonal and do not interfere with each other but only with itself.

Comment: Could you provide some detail, because I asked the same question on chatGPT it has told me that the pattern would be interference. Here the electron is in superposition of both spin up and spin down right so it has equal amplitude for traveling through both top slit and bottom slit, so in that case it should make interference pattern right?

Comment: @MeruguArunKumar ChatGPT apparently doesn’t know physics. Quite a relief.

Answer (score 0):

The EM field is responsible for interference ... even before the electron has left the electrode it is excited and strongly interacting with the EM field. If the electron's EM field interaction can see thru both slits then this field will give an interference pattern. The fact that you have gates on the slits is probably going to limit the particles EM field interaction to one slit or the other.